# Nachweis und Bedeutung von »wederer«

Tags: meaning, archaism

Online wurde bei einer Übersetzungseite (Englisch → Deutsch) das Wort *wederer* gesehen.

> whether {conj} [obs.] [which of two]
>   →
>   wederer [veraltet] [welcher von zweien auch immer]

Gibt es in einem älteren Deutschlehrbuch einen Nachweis für dieses Wort?
Ggf. mit dieser bzw. einer anderen Bedeutung?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Im [Deutschen Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/call_wbgui_py_from_form?sigle=DWB&mode=Volltextsuche&firsthit=0&textpattern=&lemmapattern=wederer&patternlist=L:wederer&lemid=GW10849&hitlist=49669796) von Jacob und Wilhelm Grimm gibt es einige Beweise und Beispiele für dieses alte Wort.

und in diesem Wörterbuch ist die Erklärung des Wortes ist wie folgt;

> **Wederer**: pron. welcher von zweien; welcher auch immer von zweien. ein gemeingerman. fragepronomen, das z. th. auch indefinit gebraucht wird, mhd. *wederer, wederre,* meist ohne flexionsendung *weder,* ahd. *hwedar, wedar, wedarer, wederer* (bei *Notker)* uter, quis (auf zwei bezogen)

Comment: Wieder was gelernt. Ich hätte das Wort glatt als Rechtschreibfehler abgetan.